Palantir Foundry - Calling webhook
So I currently have a Code Repository set up, and within this I have imported a REST API as a source (called “Gdelt2Retrieve”) . Within this REST API, I also have a webhook called ("Gdelt2) configured. I can run this in the data connection tab and successfully see the correct results from the webhook/API. I also have the egress policies set up.
I am trying to configure this webhook in a code repository, with the end goal of having this function imported into pipeline builder (This would be the input for the rest of the pipeline). If not using a function I would like to have the webhook directly in pipeline builder to run every hour or so, and dump into a dataset.
I also have the transform-external-systems setting enabled from the documentation. From my understanding, I have to call the webhook, and also have an output as a dataset.
Could somebody tell me if I am on the right track with this code? I tried to mimic the documentation:
from palantir.datasets.core import Dataset
from palantir.datasets.webhooks import WebhookClient
from pyspark.sql import function


@function(sources=["Gdelt2Retrieve"])  
def call_webhook() -> str:
    # Create a WebhookClient instance
    webhook_client = WebhookClient()

    # Execute the webhook
    try:
        response = webhook_client.execute("Gdelt2")
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: Webhook call failed due to an exception: {e}"

    # Check if the webhook execution was successful
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return f"Error: Webhook call failed with status code {response.status_code}, response: {response.text}"

    # Process the response data
    try:
        data = response.json()  # Extract JSON data
    except ValueError:
        return "Error:"


    return str(data)

Also, after importing my API: ‘Gdelt2Retrieve’, In the resources side tab it gives me this starter code:


import requests
@function(sources=["Gdelt2Retrieve"])
def my_function() -> String:
    # TODO: specify endpoint url
    response = requests.get(...)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        # Handle error
    data = response.json()
    # Use response data


I don’t necessarily need to use the function, but I figured this would be the easiest way to get a webhook integrated into the pipeline builder.

Have you tried the code? What is the outcome? What was the expected outcome? What exactly do you need help with?
